# How can I overwrite the Mongoose findOne() function on a schema for testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mongoose

I am trying to test some business logic and need to overwrite the findOne() function that is placed on a Mongoose schema.

A small workable example of what I am trying to do is:

```
function myFunc() {
  const qry = { ...search_criteria... };
  mySchema.findOne(qry)
     .exec()
     .then((doc) => { ...some business logic...})
}
```

How can I manipulate the findOne() function in a way that I can define what it will return in my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sinon`](https://sinonjs.org/) to create a [stub for this function](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/), basically completely replacing it with whatever you need.

For example:

```
const findOne = sinon.stub(mySchema, 'findOne');
findOne.callsFake((query) => { console.log('Test'); });

mySchema.findOne({}); // prints 'Test'
```